# Add Friends Function - friend already added

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application to add friends. I need to have my script to check, if the users' already friends. I thought I could do this by a COUNT. I did like this:

```
            $username = $_GET[user];
            $ven_til_id = $_SESSION['userID'];

            $num = 1;
            if(isset($_GET['add_friend'])){
                $check=("SELECT username,ven_til_id, COUNT(*) AS num FROM friends WHERE username=$username AND ven_til_id=$ven_til_id GROUP BY username,ven_til_id")or die(mysql_error());
                $result=mysql_query($check);
                    if(!$result){
                        echo "Cant run query.";
                    } else {
                        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
                    }
                    if($num>0){
                        header("Location: /profil/$username?add_error");
                } else {
                $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends (username,ven_til_id)VALUES('$username', '$ven_til_id')")or die(mysql_error());
                header("Location: /profil/$username");
                }
            }

            ?>
```

But when I'm adding one friend it's fine. It adds it and everything is fine. But then when I try to add another, it says we're already friends. I guess it's because it's counting how many times my ID (ven_til_id) is listed in the tables.

Comment: In future, when you add a code snippet, just indent it (or select everything and press the `code` button) - it should preserve the formatting properly.

Comment: I did. I tried. I don't know why it did like it did. Im sorry.

Comment: Is it because you're missing a comma after `ven_til_id` in your first SQL query? Or is that just a copy/paste error?

Comment: @Kolind No need to apologise, I just wasn't sure if you knew :)

Comment: @Kolind I've solved it and put the working version in the chat. You missed the apostrophes around `$username` in the SQL query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma:

```
SELECT
 username,ven_til_id COUNT(*) AS num  FROM ...
```

should be

```
SELECT
 username,ven_til_id, COUNT(*) AS num  FROM ...
```

Also, your reference to the count field is incorrect - it should be the third column or `$row[2]`

You may want to make your code more robust by referring to fields by name eg `$row['num']`

One final thing to confirm is that the value being retrieved with a count is being treated as an integer not a string. I don't *think* it's the problem here but you may want to explicitly cast it to avoid possible issues later eg...

```
$num = (int) $row[2];
```

**Option 1**
Just select the appropriate rows and see how many records you get back...

```
SELECT  username,
    ven_til_id
FROM    friends
WHERE   username=$username
AND     ven_til_id=$ven_til_id
```

Then just count the number of records returned using PHP - eg `mysql_num_rows()` (I think that's the correct function name)

**Clarification:**
Change

```
                    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                    $num = $row[2];
```

to

```
                    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

**Option 2**

Get MySQL to do the counting for you - in qhich case you need to tell it to group multiple record together...

```
SELECT  username,
    ven_til_id,
    COUNT(*) as Num
FROM    friends
WHERE   username=$username
AND     ven_til_id=$ven_til_id
GROUP BY username,
    ven_til_id
```

Then just read the 3rd value of the first row (`num`) and you'll have a count

NB: The second method may be overkill if you're only ever expecting a 1 or a 0

Comment: probably missing a group-by as well.

Comment: I doesn't seem like it works. My code looks like in the question (I've edited it)

Comment: @Basiclife Maybe I need an explanation of how to do the count? I wan't it to check, if there's any rows that has both username and ID to be the same as the user I'm trying to add + my USER-ID.

Comment: Maybe my problem is, that a count treats the int.. And therefore it takes the ven_til_id - which is the USER_ID. And then it's sure I can't add anymore friends cus it's already listed 1 time?

Comment: @Marc Nicely spotted - I missed that entirely on the first pass :/ I've added it in under option 2 of my answer, thanks

Comment: @Kolind one handy way to debug problems like this is to run the desired query directly against MySQL using something like MySQL Workbench or PHPMyAdmin - Then check that the results you're getting match what you expect. Once you've chosen an option to proceed, can you add the MySQL result set to your question? Thanks

Comment: @Basiclife - I've read your answer. I want to use the first option, if that's possible for me. I just don't know what you mean. As I've understand, I've done as in the question. I'll edit it

Comment: @Kolind I've added some clarification

Comment: @Basiclife I don't think you get what I'm trying to do. I don't expect the ven_til_id to be 0 or 1. That "ven_til_id" is the USER_ID of the user who added the "username" (which is the user they try to add as their friend).

Comment: @Basiclife let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2586/discussion-between-kolind-and-basiclife)